# What all services can be configured via Azure SDK for ruby

Tags: ruby, azure

I was looking at [Azure SDK for ruby](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby) and after comparing the API available there with the [list of Azure's services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn775049.aspx), I noticed that the SDK does **not** have API for achieving many of the tasks related to various services. Are the API mentioned on [SDK's github homepage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby) the **only API** available ?

Eg: It has API to create a virtual machine, but no API to add DNS server.

The SDK has API to create Virtual network which can take params **or** XML file. 
I also want to know whether we can configure other services using XML files and if yes, where can I find the XML data structure to configure those services.

The [azure documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/) is huge and I am unable to find proper reference for the XML data structure and list of services which can be configured using Ruby SDK.

**FYI** : I am on Ubuntu machine and cannot use Azure's other tools which are specific to only Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the list of services configurable by the [azure-sdk-for-ruby](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby)

- Base Management Service (creating affinity group, listing locations)
- Cloud Service
- Storage Management Service (Blob, Queue, Table)
- Service Bus Service (Queue, Topic) - Could **not** make it work.
- SQL Database Management Service
- Virtual Machine Management Service
- Virtual Image & Disk Management Service
- Virtual Network Management Service

I have created a [quick reference](https://azure-sdk-test.herokuapp.com/) of available methods and [short description of various Azure entities](https://azure-sdk-test.herokuapp.com/docs).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an Azure API client (that despite my best efforts, has remained closed source) in ruby that my company uses, and I can relate to how much of a beast their API can be.  You will find the best resources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx), which will document all of the XML that can be configured.  It might also be relevant to note that the official cross platform SDK is actually their Node.js client, which is available at [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node), which will definitely work on Ubuntu, better than the Ruby SDK.